# Change image in another div

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, image

i have in my database one table product, whit the colums

```
 product_id---nombre---imagen.

      1---pie----pie.png
```

and i use this select opction to show the name of prduct

```
<select class="form-control" name="producto_id" style="width:175px; float:left;">
     <?php foreach($producto as $c):?>
     <option value="<?php echo $c['id_productos']; ?>"><?php echo $c['nombre']; ?></option>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
```

now i want show the image of that prduct in another div but i dont have idea how to do this

Answer (score 0):

You will need the path to the image in your database (or hard-code it but I don't recommend that). Then you can simply use (include attributes, wrapper elements, etc as necessary):

`<img src="<?php echo $c['imagen']; ?>" />`

Comment: That was my first attempt but it always showed only the first image of the database regardless of whether I select another product.

Answer (score 0):

Move your loop outside of the elements first, then add each row then close the loop -

As Baledin stated, use a path to your images to load the correct path and try not to hardcode them. You can use code like this below -

```
<?php foreach($producto as $c) {
    if(isset($producto)
?>    

<select class="form-control" name="producto_id" style="width:175px; float:left;">
 <option value="<?php echo $c['id_productos']; ?>">
 <?php echo $c['nombre']; ?></option>
</select>

<div>
    <img src="<?php echo $c['imagen']; ?>" />
</div>
<?PHP
    }
?>
```